# Set opacity's volume onPress of TouchableOpacity manually in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-native, touchableopacity

I am trying to figure out how to change the volume of the opacity of TouchableOpacity component of React-Native, meaning that I do not like the default value of the opacity when the press is performed, and I would like the opacity to be less transparent.

According to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) for this purpose the [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) should be used:

> Opacity is controlled by wrapping the children in an Animated.View, which is added to the view hierarchy. Be aware that this can affect layout.

So, I did it, that's how it looks:

```
<Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.opacity._value }}>
    <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={this.hideKeyboard.bind(this)}
        style={{ opacity: this.state.opacity._value }}
    >
        <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>Cancel</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```

The **hideKeyboard** method, that is being invoked onPress, calls the **changeOpacity** method from within it, that's how it looks:

```
changeOpacity() {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.opacity, 
        {
            toValue: this.state.opacity === 1 ? 0 : 1,
            duration: 500
        }
    ).start();
}
```

**this.state.opacity** is declared in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { opacity: new Animated.Value(1) };
}
```

Having all of this, the behavior (the volume of the opacity onPress of TouchableOpacity) does not change, it is still stays default. The documentation also vaguely introduces setOpacityTo method, but I can't figure out how to use it due to the thoroughness of the description provided in the documentation. How can I perform a manual configuration of the opacity?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  activeOpacity={.7} // default is .2
  ... other props here
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that and the animation is too slow. It does not just pop between two values, but stays on .7 for a while and only then goes back.

Comment: That problem could happen in development mode generally in react native, try building a production version and check.

Comment: I created a new project which just has this TouchableOpacity and there it works as I would expect. So, the amount of code that I have in my actual project affects its performance even with Debugger turned-off, is that Correct?

Comment: It does not depend upon the amount of code, should work properly in production and on real devices.

Comment: Well, the basic project consisting only of TouchableOpacity did work correctly in the testing mode, but the actual project, as I said above, does not change the opacity back to normal as quickly as the test project.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/SkjYnYlDW check this snack demo, works fine. Working with android or ios

Comment: Exactly. The new project that I have created (which has the same code as yours) and tested in the **debugging** mode, works perfectly fine as well, but my main app consisting of multiple components and lines of code performs the opacity animation a bit slowly (not laggy, just unpleasantly slowly). 
So I am just wondering if the reason for this slow animation is the amount of code or something else.